# Considering basic intonation patterns, what is meant by "generation paths" in this excerpt?

Tags: prosody, intonation

In [this](https://www.phil.uu.nl/tst/2012/Werk/PROSTEM.pdf) description of intonation, the author claims that

> The pitch contours belonging to the same family are supposed to be manifestations of the same underlying “basic intonation pattern”.  In the grammar of intonation each basic intonation pattern can be defined as the **family of generation paths** that go through the Root configurations that corresponds to that pattern.

I'm confused by what is meant by a "generation path". Does this have to do with articulation or something else?